# How can I check if the Puppet Enterprise server/master is installed and working correctly?

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

Puppet Enterprise appeared to be installed on my ubuntu 14.04 server:

```
root@puppet:/# puppet --version
3.8.5 (Puppet Enterprise 3.8.4)
```

However, the puppet service is not running:

```
root@puppet:/# service puppet status
puppet: unrecognized service
```

The Puppet server seems to be working as well, as I can execute following command on the puppet master:

```
root@puppet:/# puppet resource package nginx
package { 'nginx':
  ensure => '1.4.6-1ubuntu3.4',
```

Puppet cert list is empty as well even after running 'puppet agent -t' on a node:

```
root@puppet:/# puppet cert list 
root@puppet:/#
```

Answer (score 6):

The puppet service is called `pe-puppet` and not `puppet` on PE 3.x.

`puppet cert list` only displays the outstanding cert requests. You want `puppet cert list --all` to display the signed certs. https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/man/cert.html

Answer (score 0):

```
service puppetmaster status
```

this will show the status of the puppet on the master machine

```
service puppet status
```

this will show the status on the slave/agent machine